# Why does my Morse code converter display no output?

Tags: bash, shell, morse-code

I want to make a morse code converter that converts letters from a txt file to morse code and morse code from a txt file to letters.

The way of execution is `./morse.sh -e Text.txt` for encoding and `./morse.sh -d Morse_text.txt` for decoding. My only problem is that the output is not displayed on the screen for some reason.

Here is the code. If I made a mistake let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello,welcome to the Morse Code Converter!!"

encode(){
    declare -A morse
    morse[A]=".-";
    morse[B]="-...";
    morse[C]="-.-.";
    morse[D]="-..";
    morse[E]=".";
    morse[F]="..-.";
    morse[G]="--.";
    morse[H]="....";
    morse[I]="..";
    morse[J]=".---";
    morse[K]="-.-";
    morse[L]=".-..";
    morse[M]="--";
    morse[N]="-.";
    morse[O]="---";
    morse[P]=".--.";
    morse[Q]="--.-";
    morse[R]=".-.";
    morse[S]="...";
    morse[T]="-";
    morse[U]="..-";
    morse[V]="...-";
    morse[W]=".--";
    morse[X]="-..-";
    morse[Y]="-.--";
    morse[Z]="--..";
    morse[1]=".----";
    morse[2]="..---";
    morse[3]="...--";
    morse[4]="....-";
    morse[5]=".....";
    morse[6]="-....";
    morse[7]="--...";
    morse[8]="---..";
    morse[9]="----.";
    morse[0]="-----";

    for (( k = 0; k < ${#morse}; k=k + 1 )); do
        echo "${morse}"
    done
}

decode(){
    declare -A letter
    letter[.-]="A";
    letter[-...]="B";
    letter[-.-.]="C";
    letter[-..]="D";
    letter[.]="E";
    letter[..-.]="F";
    letter[--.]="G";
    letter[....]="H";
    letter[..]="I";
    letter[.---]="J";
    letter[-.-]="K";
    letter[.-..]="L";
    letter[--]="M";
    letter[-.]="N";
    letter[---]="O";
    letter[.--.]="P";
    letter[--.-]="Q";
    letter[.-.]="R";
    letter[...]="S";
    letter[-]="T";
    letter[..-]="U";
    letter[...-]="V";
    letter[.--]="W";
    letter[-..-]="X";
    letter[-.--]="Y";
    letter[--..]="Z";
    letter[-----]="0";
    letter[.----]="1";
    letter[..---]="2";
    letter[...--]="3";
    letter[....-]="4";
    letter[.....]="5";
    letter[-....]="6";
    letter[--...]="7";
    letter[---..]="8";
    letter[----.]="9";

    for (( i = 0; i < ${#morse}; i=i + 1 )); do
        echo "${letter:i}"
    done
}

if [[ $1 = "-e" ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
        echo "The text is : $line"
        echo "Morse code is:"
    done < "$2"
    encode "$@"
elif [[ $1 = "-d" ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line1 || [[ -n "$line1" ]] ; do
        echo "The Morse code is : $line1"
        echo "The translation is:"
    done < "$2"
    decode "$@"
else
    echo "Please try again using -e or -d"
fi
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: A few things I can see immediately: you use `morse` both as a variable holding `$3` and an associative array; `echo $($3)` is trying to run the contents of `$3` as a command; when you call a function, the function gets its own positional parameters, so `$3` won't be what you expect within your functions; you should quote a lot more of your parameter expansions.

Comment: And the logic in your functions seems to be backwards. Everything after the `done` has no effect at all.

Comment: Hello again. I did some changes in the code and the output for the encoding function is                                                                                      ./morse.sh -e Text.txt
Hello,welcome to the Morse Code Converter!!
The text is : MORSE CODE
Morse code is:
-----
----
---
--
-                                                                                                                              I repositioned the for loops under the arrays an called the functions under done <"$2"

Comment: We ask that a question include a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible** code that describes a specific problem. Don't just dump your whole program into a question -- find the specific place where it fails, and write the shortest possible script that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: ...if you want to better figure out where and how something fails, to let you write that reproducer, use `PS4=':${LINENO}+' bash -x yourscript` to run the script with every command that it executes logged so you can track down exactly where its actual behavior first starts to deviate from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted from your code and now this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

encode_char(){
    declare -A morse
    morse[A]=".-";
    morse[B]="-...";
    morse[C]="-.-.";
    morse[D]="-..";
    morse[E]=".";
    morse[F]="..-.";
    morse[G]="--.";
    morse[H]="....";
    morse[I]="..";
    morse[J]=".---";
    morse[K]="-.-";
    morse[L]=".-..";
    morse[M]="--";
    morse[N]="-.";
    morse[O]="---";
    morse[P]=".--.";
    morse[Q]="--.-";
    morse[R]=".-.";
    morse[S]="...";
    morse[T]="-";
    morse[U]="..-";
    morse[V]="...-";
    morse[W]=".--";
    morse[X]="-..-";
    morse[Y]="-.--";
    morse[Z]="--..";
    morse[1]=".----";
    morse[2]="..---";
    morse[3]="...--";
    morse[4]="....-";
    morse[5]=".....";
    morse[6]="-....";
    morse[7]="--...";
    morse[8]="---..";
    morse[9]="----.";
    morse[0]="-----";
    morse[ ]="/"

    morse[space]="/"
    morse[return]="\n"

    echo -ne "${morse[${1}]:-/} "  # return "/" if not in dictionary
}

decode_char(){
    declare -A letter
    letter[.-]="A";
    letter[-...]="B";
    letter[-.-.]="C";
    letter[-..]="D";
    letter[.]="E";
    letter[..-.]="F";
    letter[--.]="G";
    letter[....]="H";
    letter[..]="I";
    letter[.---]="J";
    letter[-.-]="K";
    letter[.-..]="L";
    letter[--]="M";
    letter[-.]="N";
    letter[---]="O";
    letter[.--.]="P";
    letter[--.-]="Q";
    letter[.-.]="R";
    letter[...]="S";
    letter[-]="T";
    letter[..-]="U";
    letter[...-]="V";
    letter[.--]="W";
    letter[-..-]="X";
    letter[-.--]="Y";
    letter[--..]="Z";
    letter[-----]="0";
    letter[.----]="1";
    letter[..---]="2";
    letter[...--]="3";
    letter[....-]="4";
    letter[.....]="5";
    letter[-....]="6";
    letter[--...]="7";
    letter[---..]="8";
    letter[----.]="9";
    letter[/]=" ";

    letter[space]=" ";

    echo -ne "${letter[${1}]}"
}




if [[ $1 = "-e" ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
        #echo "The text is : $line"
        #echo "Morse code is:"
        for ch in $(echo "${line^^}" | grep -o . | sed 's/ /space/g') ; do  # convert line to uppercase, then convert to character array, then replace " " with something else, since for loop won't recongnize " " as an item
            encode_char "$ch"
        done
        echo
    done < "$2"
elif [[ $1 = "-d" ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line1 || [[ -n "$line1" ]] ; do
        #echo "The Morse code is : $line1"
        #echo "The translation is:"
        for ch in $(echo "${line1}" | sed 's./.\nspace\n.g') ; do  # convert "/" into a separate non-empty line
            decode_char "$ch"
        done
        echo " "
    done < "$2"
else
    echo "Please try again using -e or -d"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be a late answer, but I think this approach would be simpler:

you will need 3 files :

- The software
- The dictionnary
- The morse to translate (could be piped, or a param)

The logic approach would be to match each morse 'word' (letter) to the dictionary and outputting the result.

A simple dictionary could be like this:

```
A [.-]
B [-...]
C [-.-.]
D [-..]
E [.]
...
```

Your input should contain the text to translate on one line:
e.g.

```
.... . .-.. .-.. --- ....... .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
```

and the software could look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Get the string from the file (could be a parameter)
str=$(cat test.morse)

# Iterate over every 'word' in the string (split the spaces)
for code in $str; do
        # Find the corresponding line in the dictionnary (dict.csv)
        letter=$(grep -F "[${code}]" dict.csv  | head -c1)
        # Print the letter without caret return
        echo -n $letter
        # if the letter is empty, print a space
        if [[ "$letter" == '' ]]; then
                echo -n ' '
        fi
done
# Print a carret return at the end
echo ""
```